# Can a hacker crack this basic php url query check?

Tags: php

I'm probably going to get nailed for asking a broad question, but hopefully my super simple example will make it less broad. Imagine I have this:

```
<?php  
  $pass = '...';
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['key']) && $_REQUEST['key'] == $pass) {
        print 'super secret text';
  }

?>
```

Assuming $pass is a 64 character random number, is there a way a hacker could crack this? I'm not so worried about brute forcing. Let's assume I also have flood protection against someone repeatedly guessing. My bigger concern is that there is perhaps a way that the hacker could override the value of $pass.

Is it safe to say that there is NO WAY that a hacker could see the "super secret text" without guessing the correct value of pass?

Comment: no, but there is other attacks like mitm, or getting on your server or vcs, then hardcoded values will be your downfall over using env vars

Comment: $_REQUEST is a bit broad, I would use specific `GET/POST/Cookie`, also `strcmp` might be safer

Comment: A precisation: an hacker that uses its knowledge for bad purposes is called CRacker, not hacker.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use rather useless terms like "hacker" at all, and rather simply focus on whether there's *a bug in this code that would allow anyone to bypass the condition*…

Comment: There are many ways. Security is like night driving; things in your vision aren't the ones that gonna hit you. In your case, think of another script (wordpress or drupal php-code editing etc), that would dump the source of your script, then the super-secret is exploited)